# Advanced Threat Protection Rest API

Tags: azure, o365security-compliance

I would like to understand about the Rest API end point for "Office 365 Advanced Threat Protection and Threat Investigation".

I checked and found this -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-schema#office-365-advanced-threat-protection-and-threat-investigation-and-response-schema

But still I am not able to narrow down to the Rest API end point.

Also I checked in Azure and found this API permissions available (Click on the image link given next line). So If I can get the Rest end point URL , I can build my app with this API permissions and get the necessary data.
Click here to see the image
[Azure API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSBwO.jpg)

Let me know if I have not clearly explained.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any update here?